# Get value in dynamic line of data

Tags: javascript

I have a data that automatically generated like below :

```
1  my data 001 12values
2  my data 001 121values
3  my data 001 53values
4  my data 001 84values
5  my data 001 154values
6  my data 001 235values
7  my data 001 99values
8  my data 001 78values
9  my data 001 54values
10 my data 001 253values
11 my data 001 1043values
12 my data 001 1320values
13 my data 001 543values
14 my data 001 241values
15 my data 001 98values
```

It generated every seconds, so at data above have 15 lines in 15 seconds.

How can i get only the values every line, so other are deleted.

Just get the value of line 1 :

```
12
```

And line 2 :

```
121
```

And so on..

I already tried using `replace` :

```js
var str = "1  my data 001 12values";
var res = str.replace("1  my data 001", "");
var res2 = res.replace("values", "");
console.log(res2);
```

That's the result i expect but it just example for line 1, if i want to get the value of line 2, the number at the first character changed to 2 and so on. So i must manually change in the code `str.replace("1  my data 001", "");` to `str.replace("2  my data 001", "");`.

Anyone can help me to get the value every line without manually change the `str.replace` search value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [**`regular expression`**](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_regexp.asp) to achieve the desired result.

`\d+(?=values)`

**Details**:

`\d+` - matches a series of numbers (main pattern).

`(?=values)` - finds the main pattern which is followed by `"values"`.

```js
var str = "1  my data 001 12values";
var res = +str.match(/\d+(?=values)/i)[0];
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, it solve my problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can use  this  also

```js
var dataline = "my data 001 121values"

var datavalue = dataline.substring(dataline.lastIndexOf(" ")+1).split("v")[0]

alert("[" + datavalue + "]")
```